# About Local Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

As we know every finite ring is a finite product of finite local rings, and the orders of finite local rings are powers of primes. Then why $Z_4$ is not a product of $Z_2\times Z_2$, although $Z_2$ is a local ring.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The ring $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is already a local ring. Why should it factor?

Comment: I mean characterization of local rings of order 4, Is it necessary product of local rings is still a local ring

Comment: @Samirahmadwagay I don't know why specifically with respect the terms you know, however $\Bbb{Z}_4$ is a cyclic abelian group and $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$ is not, because ex. $\langle (0,1)\rangle = 0 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$ and $\langle (1,1) \rangle = $ two simultaneously equal copies of $\Bbb{Z}_2$ or in other words it's $\simeq \Bbb{Z}_2$.  Therefore there is no single generator for $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$, or, it's not cyclic in other words.  An isomorphism of rings is in particular an isomorphism of the underlying abelian groups.  $\blacksquare$  Or that is the usual proof of non-isom

Comment: Note that only finite *commutative* rings are products of local rings.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things: first, a product of local rings is never local, so $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ has no chance of being local.

There are exactly $4$ unital rings of order $4$, all of them being commutative:

- $\mathbb{Z}_4$, which is local, and in particular a product of local rings (a trivial product with just itself);
- $\mathbb{F}_4$ (the field with $4$ elements), which is also local (and so also a product of local rings);
- $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$, which is not local (see above), but is the product of two local rings (namely $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$);
- $\mathbb{Z}_2[\varepsilon]$ with $\varepsilon^2=0$. This is the only non-reduced ring in the list, and it is also local (so a product of local rings).

So as you see indeed all rings of order $4$ are product of local rings, but $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$, and there is no contradiction (I actually don't understand at all why you thought there was one).

Comment: yes I got you, my question was actually like that  , is product of local rings still a local ring.